# Regular Expressions Testbed

Tags: c, regex, tdd, testbed

I am currently attempting to implement a regular expression engine.  (Yes, for fun.  Go fig.)

I am working from this site for general algorithmic approach: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

My question for you all is: do you know of a collection of regular expressions and text strings that I can use as a comprehensive testbed for my engine?  I've been searching and asking around for a couple days now, and can't find anything specific; maybe my google keyword-fu is lacking.

Thanks!

p.s. By way of example:

regexs:

- "a"
- "abc"
- "^a$"
- "[a-c]"
- "^[^a]$"
- "^[^a]?$"
- "a+"
- "."
- ".*"
- ".+"
- "da?[bd]"

strings:

- ""
- "a"
- "h"
- "dd"
- "abc"
- "dad"
- "dabcd"
- "aaaaab"

Comment: +1 for the linked article, it's really interesting. Sorry that I can't help on the actual question, but may I ask if you know whether the performance problems in Perl/Python/Ruby etc. are still present?

Comment: Yes, they are still present -- have to be, as long as they support back-references.  Luckily the problem is just in pathological cases, but then it's horrible!

Comment: I've also seen very simple regexes like `^[asd3kgnvo]*$` perform very poorly compared to other approaches (especially in Java and Python). This is astonishing, as they have a lot of potential for optimization, I imagine. **EDIT:** Just found the performance test from a recent question: http://ideone.com/oPKYq Made me really sad :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long ago I wrote a simple filename pattern matching function (file patterns are a special subset of regyular expressions). In the code (in C) I provided a few dozen test cases. You could probably adapt them for use with a regular expression matcher.

Source is at:
• http://david.tribble.com/src/fpattern.c
• http://david.tribble.com/src/fpattern.h

Comment: Excellent, that looks like a great starting place for me!